# Почему возвращает пустой список?

Tags: python

Почему возвращает пустой список?

```
def count_smileys(arr):
    stack = []
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        for j in range(i):
            if arr[i][j] == ":" or arr[i][j] == ";":
                stack.append(arr[i][j])
            elif arr[i][j] == "~" or arr[i][j] == "-":
                if stack == 0:
                    return False
                else:
                    stack.append(arr[i][j])
            elif arr[i][j] == "D" or arr[i][j] == ")":
                if stack == 0:
                    return False
                else:
                    stack.append(arr[i][j])
        return stack

print(count_smileys([':D',':~)',';~D',':)']))         #, 4
print(count_smileys([':)',':(',':D',':O',':;']))      #, 2
print(count_smileys([';]', ':[', ';*', ':$', ';-D'])) #, 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы, наверно, хотите подсчитать **количество** смайликов в данном списке строк.

Притом смайлик для вас значит:

- строку из 2 или 3 символов, в которой

  - первым знаком будет `:` или `;`
  - второй знак может быть `-` или `~`, но его можно пропустить,
  - последний знак должен быть `D` или `)`

Вы хотите подсчитать смайлики — начинаем с нуля:

```
def count_smileys(arr):
    counter = 0
```

Выбираем очередную строку из списка:

```
    for strn in arr:
```

Определим количество символов в ней:

```
        num_char = len(strn)
```

Когда оно не подходит, бросим эту строку — просто продолжаем проходить циклом, выбирая следующую строку:

```
        if num_char not in (2, 3):
            continue
```

Когда команда `continue` не выполнилась, знаем, что наша строка состоит из 2 или 3 символов. Когда первой из них нет `:` или `;`, опять строку бросим:

```
        if strn[0] not in ":;":
            continue
```

То же самое с последним символом:

```
        if strn[-1] not in "D)":
            continue
```

Но и теперь всё зависит от количества символов — когда их в строке только 2, это смайлик, повисим количество смайликов и продолжаем работать со следующей строкой:

```
        if num_char == 2:
           counter += 1
           continue
```

Когда это не случилось знаем, что количество символов равно 3, 1-й и последний подходит, значит, всё зависит от среднего (2-го, т.е. с индексом `1`):

```
        if strn[1] not in "-~":
            continue
```

Когда мы до сих пор не бросили строку, она подходит — это смайлик — и подсчитаем её:

```
        counter += 1
```

После окончания тестирования строк — выхода из цикла — в переменной `counter` уже количество всех смайликов, и мы ее возвратим:

```
    return counter
```

Всё.

---

**Вся функция:**

```
def count_smileys(arr):
    counter = 0

    for strn in arr:
        num_char = len(strn)
 
        if num_char not in (2, 3):
            continue
        if strn[0] not in ":;":
            continue
        if strn[-1] not in "D)":
            continue
        if num_char == 2:
            counter += 1
            continue
        if strn[1] not in "-~":
            continue

        counter += 1
    return counter
```

---

*Тестировка с вашими списками:*

```
print(count_smileys([':D',':~)',';~D',':)']))         #, 4
print(count_smileys([':)',':(',':D',':O',':;']))      #, 2
print(count_smileys([';]', ':[', ';*', ':$', ';-D'])) #, 1
```

выдаст

> ```
> 4
> 2
> 1
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Первая ошибка здесь:

```
        for j in range(i):
```

должно быть

```
        for j in range(len(arr[i])):
```

Вторая в обоих

```
            if stack == 0:
```

т.к. это всегда будет `False`, потому что вы в начале определили `stack` как **список**.
Может быть, вы хотели

```
            if stack == []          # когда список пустой
```

Третья ошибка:

```
            return False
```

т.к. этим все заканчивается — функция возвратит `False` а никаких дальнейших проходов циклами не будет.

Я написал только 3 ошибки, но это не все. По моему надо сделать все заново, по-другому.

Comment: Еще ошибка (вытекающая из третьей): функция возвращает иногда False, а иногда список.

Answer (score 1):

Ваша задача как сделана для применения регулярки:

```
import re

def count_smileys(arr):
    counter = 0

    pattern = re.compile(r"[:;][-~]?[D)]$")

    for strn in arr:
        if pattern.match(strn):
            counter += 1
            
    return counter
```

В регулярном выражении

```
[:;][-~]?[D)]$
```

- `[:;]` значит, что первым символом должно быть двоеточие или точка с запятой,
- `[-~]?` значит, что следующий символ должен быт `-` или `~`, или его возможно пропустить (`?`)
- `[D)]` значит `D` или `)`
- `$` значит конец строки.

`pattern.match(strn)` сравняет **начало** строки `strn` c этим регулярным выражением.

Comment: почему мой код не работает? def count_smileys(arr):
    stack_1 = []
    stack_2 = []
    for i in range(len(arr)):
        for j in range(len(arr[i])):
            if arr[i][j] in ":;":
                stack_1.append(arr[i])
                break
    for i in range(len(stack_1)):
        for j in range(len(stack_1[i])):
            if stack_1[i][j] in "~-D)":
                stack_2.append(stack_1[i])
                break
    for i in stack_2:
        if i[-1] not in "D)":
            stack_2.remove(i)
    return len(stack_2)

Comment: На первый взгляд потому, что команда `break` *полностью прекращает внутренний цикл*. - Лучше написать ваш код в виде нового вопроса, его в формате комментария невозможно читать.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re
def count_smileys(arr):
    buffer = [''.join(re.findall(r"[:;][-~]?[D)]$", x)) for x in arr]
    return len([x for x in buffer if x != ''])
```

решил так, подглядел вашу регулярку :D